# React-native hot loading not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-hot-loader

I'm creating a react-native app. I'm using TypeScript to write the code and then transpile it to ES5. The hot loading was working perfectly yesterday, but I've made some changes to the file structure and now even if I go back to the earlier commit where hot loading was working yesterday, it does not now.

React native packager sends the HMR update to the client and the Android phone even displays the "Hot loading..." message, but after that nothing happens, I don't see the changes I've made. If I do a full refresh, I can see the changes. The component is implemented as an ES6 class, so the hot loading should be working (it was before, the class didn't change).

I've tried restarting the packager, computer, cleaning the packager cache etc., but nothing helped. I'm using Windows 10 and an Android 5 phone.

Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so apparently, HMR works only when transpiling to ES6 using ES6 modules. I've changed transpilation target for TypeScript to es5 and module format to commonjs (and forgot about it, of course :)). That was the issue. Now I'm using es6 for both and HMR is working.